# A very simple question about multinomial distributions

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Let's say you have a random vector $(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ that has a multinomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $(p_1,\ldots,p_k)$.  Suppose that we know $p_i>p_j$ for some $i,j$.  Is it correct to say that the event $x_i>x_j$ occurs with high probability i.e.
$\lim_{n\to\infty}Pr(x_i>x_j) = 1$?  This seems trivial to me (or maybe it follows by some simple law of large numbers argument).

Answer (score 1):

The marginal distribution of $x_i$ is binomial with parameters $n$ and $p_i$, so $E[x_i] = n p_i$, and thus $E[x_i - x_j] = n (p_i - p_j)$.  The covariance matrix of $x_i$ and $x_j$ is $\pmatrix{n p_i (1-p_i) & -n p_i p_j\cr -n p_i p_j & n p_j (1-p_j)}$, so the variance of $x_i - x_j$ is 
$$\text{var}(x_i) - 2 \text{cov}(x_i, x_j) + \text{var}(x_j) = n p_i (1-p_i) + 2 n p_i p_j +  n p_j (1-p_j) = n c $$
where $c = p_i (1-p_i) + 2 p_i p_j +   p_j (1-p_j) > 0$ (assuming $ p_i, p_j < 1$).
By Chebyshev's inequality, 
$Pr(x_i - x_j < 0) \le 1/k^2$ where 
$$k = E[x_i - x_j]/\sqrt{\text{var}(x_i - x_j)} = \sqrt{n} \;\dfrac{p_i - p_j}{c }$$
Since we're taking $p_i$ and $p_j$ fixed with $p_i > p_j$, $k \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, and thus $P(x_i \ge x_j) \to 1$.  Take a slightly smaller 
$k$ and you can conclude $P(x_i > x_j) \to 1$.

Comment: Bravo... thank you for helping me make it formal!